# Help on error Notice on Modules page

Tags: 7

I have the following Notices and Warning on the Modules page:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in system_sort_modules_by_info_name()
>   (line 951 of /var/www/vhosts/site
>   name/httpdocs/modules/system/system.admin.inc). Warning: uasort()
>   [function.uasort]: Array was modified by the user comparison function
>   in system_modules() (line 802 of /var/www/vhosts/site
>   name/httpdocs/modules/system/system.admin.inc). Notice: Undefined
>   index: name in _system_modules_build_row() (line 988 of
>   /var/www/vhosts/site name/httpdocs/modules/system/system.admin.inc).

I have searched on the internet for examples of this issue and found some, but the answers didn't help me, because it was about an error in a module i didn't have installed or the answer was too complex for me. Could anyone help me with above error?

I don't even know to which module it is related.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a [bug report](https://www.drupal.org/node/939498). Please keep discussion of bug reports in the issue queues on Drupal.org. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if this should not be here, it can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/939498) and there is available [patch file](https://www.drupal.org/node/939498#comment-9544719) for Drupal 7 and UTF-8 file encoding.

So your options are:

- Disable the notice in site settings or in PHP configuration.
- Wait until patch is committed and upgrade your Drupal core.
- Disable faulty module.
- [Apply the patch your-self](https://www.drupal.org/patch).
- Apply patch manually by [opening it](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/notice-undefined-index-939498-34_0.patch) and check the changes:

  ```
  --- a/includes/common.inc
  +++ b/includes/common.inc
  @@ -7369,7 +7369,8 @@ function drupal_parse_info_format($data) {
     $constants = get_defined_constants();

     if (preg_match_all('
  -    @^\s*                           # Start at the beginning of a line, ignoring leading whitespace
  +    @^(?:\xEF\xBB\xBF)?             # Check for UTF-8 byte order mark and remove it
  +    \s*                             # Start at the beginning of a line, ignoring leading whitespace
  ```

  where on the top is the file to edit which is `includes/common.inc` (ignore `a`/`b`), 3rd line is the line number, then remove the lines which starts with minus and replace them these with pluses (without plus signs). If you got the error, then double check your syntax or revert your file to the previous version.